# Starting ipython in 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, python-3.4

I have Anaconda and Python (both 3.4 and 2.7) installed in my system and Python 3.4 is the default one. Because of this whenever I launch ipython it opens in 3.4. Is there a way to start ipython in Python 2.7?
Or any way we can choose what version to start every time we launch ipython?

Comment: On Linux at least, you usually have symlinks to `ipython2`, `ipython2.7` `ipython3` and `ipython3.4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and can only vouch for how the following works on that OS; I have not tried it on any other platform.

To use IPython for a specific version of Python, you can use the `ipython2` and `ipython3` commands respectively.

If you want to change the default Python version used when use the `ipython` command, first locate the command:

```
$ which ipython
```

For me on Ubuntu 16.04 it is at `/usr/local/bin/ipython`. Next, open that file in a text editor. For me, the file contents are as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

The line `#!/usr/bin/python` determines which version of Python will be used for `ipython`. Simply change this to point to your Python 2.7 executable (you can locate this with `which python2.7`) if you want that to be the default.

Comment: Okay, I got it.
I had to go to the /bin and add another executable file with the name ipython2.

Thank you for answering! :)